# ウェブサイト上でs3のバケット一覧を取得したい

Tags: aws, amazon-s3

サイト上でs3のバケット一覧を取得したいのですが、CORSに引っかかってしまい取得することができません。

> Access to fetch at 'https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?x-id=ListBuckets' from origin 'https://s3.amazonaws.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

このサイトもs3に設置してあります。
個々のバケットにはCORSの設定を施しましたが、s3自体のCORS設定方法がわかりません。
初歩的な質問で申し訳ないですが、よろしくお願いします。